# The multi-part identifier "t.tag_instrument_id_fk" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new here specifically for this problem...I already search every topic and none has helped me so far.

I am trying to create a little report but the error that "could not be bound" is hunting me.

```
select i.ins_serial_number AS "Serial",
       t.tag_tag AS "TAG",
       tg.tcv_strategy_id_ck AS "Estrategia", 
       tg.tcv_cal_value AS "Valor", 
       tg.tcv_error_tolerance as "Crit Aceit",
       un.un_unit as "Unidade"
from tag_cal_values as tg, 
     units as un,
     tags as t,
     inst_scales as sc
left outer join instruments as i 
    on i.ins_instrument_id_pk = t.tag_instrument_id_fk 
where t.tag_tag_id_pk = tg.tcv_tag_id_ck
    and un.un_unit_id_pk = sc.isc_input_unit_id_fk
```

message 4104, level 16, state 1, line 1
The multi-part identifier "t.tag_instrument_id_fk" could not be bound.

The column name, table, etc is all okay.

obs: actuall I'm not expert in SQL, so...
I'm running this query in SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

Thanks :)

Comment: You need to be consistent with your join syntax. You are mixing ANSI-89 and ANSI-92 style joins. This is a mess to work with. Use ANSI-92 style joins for everything and don't use a comma separated list of tables. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: You need to edit the question to show the columns in each table (ideally include the CREATE TABLE statements), otherwise it's really hard for us to work out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax:

```
from tags t JOIN
     tag_cal_values tg
     on  t.tag_tag_id_pk = tg.tcv_tag_id_ck cross join
     units un join
     inst_scales as sc
     un.un_unit_id_pk = sc.isc_input_unit_id_fk left join
     instruments as i 
     on i.ins_instrument_id_pk = t.tag_instrument_id_fk
```

This will fix the syntax problem.  I doubt this does anything useful, though.  It looks like you are missing one or more `join` conditions.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell tags is trying to use the fk from instruments to join in with the rest of the tables. Since instruments comes later in the query it is messing it up.  For future reference you really should not be mixing your join styles, I personally like doing INNER JOIN, LEFT OUTER JOIN etc for every table I am using.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Joshua, and thanks for jumping in. While I agree with everything you posted, it's really more of a comment, which, I know, you don't have the reputation points to post. Just letting you know. :)